# EF6 Code First - Multiple one-to-many and same entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity model that contains multiple definitions to another entity. I can get one definition to work, but not both.

```
public class Inspection : Entity<int>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InspectionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Report")]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }

    public virtual Report Report { get; set; }

    ....

    public virtual ICollection<ResidentialDescriptionItem> ResidentialDescriptionItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResidentialDescriptionItem> ResidentialOtherDescriptionItems { get; set; }
}


public class ResidentialDescriptionItem : Entity<int>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ResidentialDescriptionItemId { get; set; }

    public int InspectionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("InspectionId")]
    public virtual Inspection Inspection { get; set; }

    //public int Inspection1Id { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("Inspection1Id")]
    //public virtual Inspection Inspection1 { get; set; }
}
```

I've made numerous attempts with that second index and received just as many different errors. The above configuration results in

> Unable to determine the principal end of the
> 'MySolution.EntityFramework.ResidentialDescriptionItem_Inspection'
> relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

I would like to maintain a full configuration with navigation on both sides. How do I do this using Code First and Annotations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to implement such complex relationship with annotations, but here is a demo, how you would need to override your `DbContext.OnModelCreating`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Parent
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Child> OtherChildren { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OtherParent")]
        public int? OtherParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OtherParentId")]
        public virtual Parent OtherParent { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Children)
                .WithOptional(x => x.Parent);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .HasMany(x => x.OtherChildren)
                .WithOptional(x => x.OtherParent);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());

            var ctx = new MyDbContext("Data Source=DESKTOP-5PVJ0I5;Database=test1;Integrated Security=true");

            var parent = ctx.Parents.Add(new Parent());

            ctx.Children.Add(new Child()
            {
                OtherParent = parent
            });

            ctx.Children.Add(new Child()
            {
                Parent = parent
            });

            ctx.SaveChanges();

            parent = ctx.Parents
                .Include(x => x.Children)
                .Include(x => x.OtherChildren)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]